# Why are tuples of Integers treated differently from tuples of Int64 when checking against Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number?

Tags: types, julia

I'm trying to learn Julia's type system, and I've come across something that puzzles me: both
`Integer <: T where T <: Number`
and
`Int64 <: T where T <: Number`
evaluate to true, yet
`Tuple{Vararg{Integer}} <: Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number`
evaluates to false while
`Tuple{Vararg{Int64}} <: Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number`
evaluates to true. Can someone explain to me why this is so?

Also, is there anything I could put instead of `Tuple{Vararg{T}}` to make `Tuple{Vararg{Integer}}` match? (Other than Integer itself).

I've tried reading the documentation on types but couldn't really find my answer there. But I'm thinking I might have just misunderstood or skipped something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant documentation about this is here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/types/#Diagonal-types

The idea is that `Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number` represents tuples like `Tuple{T, T, ... T}` where `T` is any **concrete** number type (like `Int`, `Float32`, `ComplexF64`, etc.), **not** an abstract type (like `Integer`, `AbstractFloat`, etc.). So these are true:

```
Tuple{Float32, Float32} <: Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number # true
Tuple{Vararg{Int64}} <: Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number    # true
```

But these are **not** true:

```
Tuple{Float32, ComplexF32} <: Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number # false
Tuple{Int32, Int64} <: Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number        # false
```

Now look at this:

```
Tuple{Int32, Int64} <: Tuple{Vararg{Integer}} # true
```

Makes sense, `Int32 <: Integer` and `Int64 <: Integer`. So, we can't allow
`Tuple{Vararg{Integer}} <: Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number` since that would create a contradiction with respect to whether `Tuple{Int32, Int64}` is a subtype of `Tuple{Vararg{T}} where T<:Number`.

For the second question, I don't know what the intent is, but `Tuple{Vararg{Integer}} <: Tuple{Vararg{Number}}` is true.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'd been looking through the documentation in Base and had completely missed that there was more on types in Developer Documentation.